# How can I make program to detect if real time protection is on?

Tags: c#

I want to detect if real time protection is on , like if user starts my program it would tell - your `RealTimeProtection` is on and might block some things !
I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Well I Want To Warn Them About It , I just need a message that says your Real Time Protection Is On

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only goal is to detect whether that option is enabled or disabled your best bet is to find the registry key where windows keeps that setting.

After some [Googling](https://superuser.com/a/982056/172195) we'll find that it is stored at registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection` in key `DisableRealtimeMonitoring` so with that info the solution becomes trivial.

The following code, when run in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), will output if that registrykey exists and if its value is set to 1.

Note that we need to call [`OpenBaseKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey?view=netframework-4.8) to get the 64bits hive of the registry in case your process is running as a 32 bits process.

The rest is straight forward with an [`OpenSubKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey?view=netframework-4.8) and [`GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue?view=netframework-4.8) to get the info we need.

Note that you don't have write permission on that key. You need to elevate first to change it.

```
// using Microsoft.Win32;

var path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection";
var key = "DisableRealtimeMonitoring";
var regkey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
if (regkey != null) {
  var subkey = regkey.OpenSubKey(path);
  var val = subkey.GetValue( key );
  if (val != null && val is Int32) {
    var value = (int) val;
    if (value == 1) {
        value.Dump("Protection is off");
    } else {
        value.Dump("Protection is on");
    }
  } else {
     "probably".Dump("Protection is on");
  }
} else {
   "huh?".Dump("key is not found");
}
```

Now go warn your users if you indeed find they have disabled this real-time protection. You don't want them to run into trouble.

Comment: Thank You ! I Also Found New Way With Service , Like If Service WdNisSvc Is Running Means Real Time Protection Is On !